# Avoid duplicating logic to handle functions that might not always return a value

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I often want to display the results of a filter (or some other lookup style function) but avoid displaying '#N/A' if the filter cannot find any matches. As I result, end up with the filter in an if block that checks for the '#N/A' result, and displays either a blank value or the results of the filter; like so:

```
=IF(ISNA(FILTER(...)),"",FILTER(...))
```

The problem is, this means that I have change the initial filter, I have to carefully do so twice. Ideally I would like something that can allow me to do the filter once, use it's value if it has one or if the result was an '#N/A' display some other default value or function. Something like:

```
=IFVALUEELSE(FILTER(...),"")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap any function with `IFERROR(function goes here)`

if you want to leave #N/A blank use this:

```
=iferror(FILTER(...))
```

if you want to add your own value in place of #N/A use this:

```
=iferror(FILTER(...),"Some value of your choice")
```

Comment: wow, perfect. Exactly what I wanted. Thanks!